# FDA Press Releases/Announcements

Tags: api, openfda

I am looking at the openFDA documentation and I don't see an endpoint to gather all of their press releases/announcements.  Can I back into that using the existing api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, such an endpoint is not yet available in openFDA.